# JavaScript how to ensure user enters a number between 1 and 100

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello i want the user to enter a number between 1 and 100 any higher i want it to display array out of bounds and not add the number to the array here is what i have and it works but when u enter in another number it says NAN

```
for(var i = 0; Repeat !== 'n'; i++){
    Student.push(prompt("Enter Student Name: "));
    Mark.push(parseInt (prompt("Enter Student mark: ")));
    //Check if Mark entered is not out of bounds and gives a grade
    if (Mark[i] <0 || Mark[i] >100){
        alert("Grate out of bounds");
         Mark.splice(i);//Removes array if out of bounds
    }else if (Mark[i] >= 83){
        getGrade.push("A");
        A++;
    }else if (Mark[i] >= 70){
        getGrade.push ("B");
        B++;
    }else if (Mark[i] >= 50){
        getGrade.push ("C");
        C++;    
    }else if (Mark[i] >= 0){
        getGrade.push ("F");
        F++;
    //If mark is not a number
    }else if (isNaN(Mark)){
    alert("Must input numbers");
    }
    Repeat = prompt ("Do you want to enter another student: y/n");
}
```

Comment: Where does it say NAN?  What says NAN?

Comment: i enter a number thats out of bounds it removes it i go to enter a number after that is displays "Must input numbers"

Comment: Also you are currently calling `isNan(Mark)` on the array object, rather than the specific mark that was entered.  I think you meant `isNan(Mark[i])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enter an incorrect value, the array is no longer in sync with `i`.  For example, if you enter (`Bob` and `1000`) for the first grade, consider what gets stored into the variables after the call to `Mark.splice(i)`:

```
Student = [Bob]
Mark = []
```

Now `Mark` is empty, and `i` has been incremented to `1`.  Let's say you now enter values `Johnny` and `50`.  Your variables look like this:

```
Student = [Bob, Johnny]
Mark = [50]
```

Notice that when your code is validating the grade, there is no `Mark[1]`, because the array only contains one value and `i` is looking at the second entry - thus `NaN`.  Also, you have more entries in `Student` than you do in `Mark`.

---

As a general principle, you should not "commit" the data until you have finished all your validation logic.  So store the entered amounts in temporary variables, check them, and then finally add them to the array at the end once you have good input data:

```
var entryStudent = prompt("Enter Student Name: ");
var entryMark = parseInt (prompt("Enter Student mark: "));
//Check if Mark entered is not out of bounds and gives a grade
...
//Once you have determined the values are valid, add them to the array
if (valid) {
  Student.push(entryStudent);
  Mark.push(entryMark);
} else {
  // make sure i is moved back to previous entry so you don't skip one
  i--;
}
```

This code isn't complete (for example, you need to figure out how to determine whether `valid` is `true` or `false`), but it should give you the general idea.

Comment: wow thanks that makes so much sence I cant believe I didn't know that

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest 2 things -

1. Make your "isNaN" check before any other checks (so you wouldn't insert wrong values).
2. Store the parseInt result in a variable, make all the checks on that variable, and only if it passes - push it into *Marks*. That way you can avoid holding the i reference.

Something like this:

```
var grade, name;
for (var i = 0; Repeat !== 'n'; i++) {
    name = prompt("Enter Student Name: ");
    grade = parseInt(prompt("Enter Student mark: "));

    // check if grade entered is a number
    if (isNaN(grade)) {
        alert("Must input numbers");
        continue;
    }
    // check if grade entered is not out of bounds
    if (grade < 0 || grade > 100) {
        alert("Grade out of bounds");
        continue;        
    }
    // store the data
    Student.push(name);
    Mark.push(grade);

    if (grade >= 83) {
        getGrade.push("A");
        A++;
    } else if (grade >= 70) {
        getGrade.push("B");
        B++;
    } else if (grade >= 50) {
        getGrade.push("C");
        C++;
    } else if (grade >= 0) {
        getGrade.push("F");
        F++;
    }
    Repeat = prompt("Do you want to enter another student: y/n");
}
```